# How to pass selected attributes to dropdown in html using query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

```
 <select    multiple="multiple" name="colors[]" id="color">
    <option value="" >choose color</option>
    <option value="black"   >Black</option>
    <option value="white" >White</option>
    <option  value="green" >Green</option>
    <option  value="red" >red</option>
  </select>
```

in this dropdown I want to pass selected attributes
eg:

```
<option  value="red" selected >red</option>
```

using jquery and how to pass set multiple select

```
<option  value="red" selected >red</option> 
<option  value="white" selected >white</option>
```

if my values of colors comes from a database like eg:yellow ,blue how to store to store in that database
mycode :
var colorstoadd=yellow ,blue

```
$("#color").find('input[type="select"]').append('<option value='+colorstoadd+ 'selected'+'>'+colorstoadd+'</option>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data returned from database like `"yellow , red , green";`

You can use the next code

- Split colors using `.split(',')`
- Loop through the array of colors after `split` by using `.each`
- Use `.trim()` to avoid any left/right white-spaces

```js
let colorstoadd = "yellow , red , green";

$.each(colorstoadd.split(',') , (i , color) => {
  $("#color").append('<option value="'+color.trim()+'" selected>'+color.trim()+'</option>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select    multiple="multiple" name="colors[]" id="color">
  <option value="" >choose color</option>
  <option value="black" >black</option>
</select>
```

**Additional**

- To check the color already exists in the dropdown use `if($("#color option[value='"+color+"']").length)`
- To add selected attribute `$("#color option[value='"+color+"']").attr("selected" , true);`

```js
let colorstoadd = "yellow , red , green";

$.each(colorstoadd.split(',') , (i , color) => {
  if($("#color option[value='"+color.trim()+"']").length){
    $("#color option[value='"+color.trim()+"']").attr("selected" , true);
  }else{
    $("#color").append('<option value="'+color.trim()+'" selected>'+color.trim()+'</option>')
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select    multiple="multiple" name="colors[]" id="color">
  <option value="" >choose color</option>
  <option value="black" >black</option>
  <option value="red" >RED</option>
</select>
```

Comment: for add selected attributes to option tag ?

Comment: @viswanathan answer updated